# Trying to fill NaN values with a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This

```
df.loc[df['Feature reference #'] == feature][development_column] = df.loc[df['Feature reference #'] == feature][development_column].fillna(req_dict[feature])
```

is the line of code which I am trying to fix. Basically, when I print

```
df.loc[df['Feature reference #'] == feature][development_column].fillna(req_dict[feature])
```

it shows the updated series with the `NaN` values replaced. But I want this updated series to be saved in the original DF.

Also tried `inplace=True` no luck with that too.

I basically want the above line of code to work as it is logically.

Comment: Chaining index when assigning new value is [bad](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). Try: `df.loc[df['Feature reference#']==feature, development_columns] = df.loc[...].fillna(req_dic[feature])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can either use:

```
df.loc[df['Feature reference #'] == feature, development_column] = df.loc[df['Feature reference #'] == feature, development_column].fillna(req_dict[feature])
```

or

```
df.loc[df['Feature reference #'] == feature, development_column].fillna(req_dict[feature], inplace=True)
```